# spring boot actuator Site working on Localhost need to expose to private network

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, localhost

I have bound a few spring boot actuator endpoints jar file metrics to ports 9000, 9001 and 9002. On trying localhost:9000 or server IP:9000. I am able to access the metrics.

But this works only on the local server. I want that any on my company network can open the metric site through IP based URL i.e IP:9000.

How can I achieve this without using tomcat or xamp. It is a spring boot actuator.

Comment: spring boot comes with an integrated tomcat server, so no need for that. You need to keep your application running on your computer, open the ports to be accessible from your network and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thankyou  @AmirSchnell opening the ports worked . Thanks